# Delete post if featured image is smaller than Y pixels by Y pixels

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I want do delete post if its featured image is smaller then eg 100x100 pixels.

Please help me modify this code.

```
 <?php
    function modify_post_thumbnail_html($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr) {
        $id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); // gets the id of the current post_thumbnail (in the loop)
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, $size); // gets the image url specific to the passed in size (aka. custom image size)
        $alt = get_the_title($id); // gets the post thumbnail title
        $class = $attr['class']; // gets classes passed to the post thumbnail, defined here for easier function access

        // Check to see if a 'retina' class exists in the array when calling "the_post_thumbnail()", if so output different <img/> html
        if (strpos($class, 'retina') !== false) {
            $html = '<img src="" alt="" data-src="' . $src[0] . '" data-alt="' . $alt . '" class="' . $class . '" />';
        } else {
            $html = '<img src="' . $src[0] . '" alt="' . $alt . '" class="' . $class . '" />';
        }

        return $html;
    }
    add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'modify_post_thumbnail_html', 99, 5);
    ?>
```

Comment: how does the posted code relate to the intended deletion of a post, based on featured image size?

Comment: It recognizes retina images. If there is such it leaves the post untouched. If there is no retina image then it replaces it with the default image.

Comment: Actually I don't know if this is the right approach. Some other guy write that code for me.